# Pyomo stops after one iteration

Tags: pyomo

With the following code, Pyomo stops after just one iteration, while I would expect it to minimize the function and iterate more:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var([0, 1], domain = pyo.NonNegativeIntegers, initialize = [10, 3])
def loss(args):
    a, b = args[0].value, args[1].value
    return (a - 30) ** 2 + (b - 5) ** 2
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = loss((model.x[0], model.x[1])), sense = pyo.minimize)
model.c1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = model.obj >= 0.0)
solver_options = pyo.SolverFactory("cbc").options
solver_options["max_iter"] = 10
solver_options["tolerance"] = 0.000001
solver_options["max_seconds"] = 10
results = pyo.SolverFactory("cbc").solve(model, options = solver_options)
results.write()
```

(In this case, the function `loss` is trivial, but in practice, I have a very complex function relying on external packages.)

The output is:

```
# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 404.0
  Upper bound: 404.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 2
  Number of variables: 1
  Number of nonzeros: 0
  Sense: minimize
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.0
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: None
      Number of created subproblems: None
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.008995532989501953
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solution Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0
```

It does not even seem to try to find a proper minimizer.

Comment: You are using an inappropriate solver.  `cbc` is for linear problem expressions.  You are squaring your variables (obviously non-linear).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a constant objective:

```py
def loss(args):
    a, b = args[0].value, args[1].value
    return (a - 30) ** 2 + (b - 5) ** 2
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = loss((model.x[0], model.x[1])), sense = pyo.minimize)
```

The `.value` attribute returns the *current value* of the variable (in this case, `x[0]` and `x[1]`) *when the expression is being defined*.  If you look at the model you are declaring, you will see that the objective is a constant 404:

```py
>>> model.pprint()
1 Set Declarations
    x_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {0, 1}

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=2, Index=x_index
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
          1 :     0 :     3 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize :      404.0

1 Constraint Declarations
    c1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
        None :   0.0 :  obj :  +Inf :   True

4 Declarations: x_index x obj c1
```

You want to create an *expression* for your objective, so you should generally *not* use `.value` (or, for that matter, `value()`):

```py
def loss(args):
    a, b = args[0], args[1]
    return (a - 30) ** 2 + (b - 5) ** 2
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = loss((model.x[0], model.x[1])), sense = pyo.minimize)
```

would give

```py
>>> model.pprint()
1 Set Declarations
    x_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {0, 1}

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=2, Index=x_index
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 :    10 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
          1 :     0 :     3 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : (x[0] - 30)**2 + (x[1] - 5)**2

1 Constraint Declarations
    c1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
        None :   0.0 :  obj :  +Inf :   True

4 Declarations: x_index x obj c1
```

At this point, @AirSquid's comment is spot on: you have a quadratic integer program, and will need to find a compatible solver (CBC does not handle QPs).

Finally, while the updated `loss()` function is more likely to do what you want, there are other (potentially more clear or concise) ways to express the same model:

```py
def obj_rule(m):
    return (m.x[0] - 30)**2 + (m.x[1] - 5)**2
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)
```

or

```py
@model.Objective(sense=pyo.minimize)
def obj(m):
    return (m.x[0] - 30)**2 + (m.x[1] - 5)**2
```